# MySQL SSL settings for ODBC

Tags: mysql

I am a SQL Server DBA configuring an SSIS package that uses a connection to a remote vendor MySQL database instance.

The vendor has sent us 3 files to implement SSL transport to their MySQL database. The filenames are: ca.pem, client-cert.pem, client-key.pem. We're currently connecting to their instance via ODBC driver MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver, version 5.03.09.00 supplied by Oracle.  I see that there is a selection for working with SSL when configuring the ODBC connection (see screen shot). Can someone advise me on how to set up these 3 files in this context?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To connect using SSL from the client side. Use the following mapping

- ssl key = `\\folderpath\client-key.pem`
- ssl certificate = `\\folderpath\client-cert.pem`
- ssl ca = `\\folderpath\ca.pem`

<sup>***Reference:** Created using comment from [samosql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/113920/samosql)*</sup>